# Inject Context in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, android-context

I am writing espresso tests for my Android application. I have an `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, where I want to inject a context to use a test database instead of the actual database.

The test context I create in the `setUp()` method like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    RenamingDelegatingContext context = 
            new RenamingDelegatingContext(getContext(), "test_");
    mActivity = getActivity();
    // Now how do I inject the new context to the activity?
}
```

How can I inject this context into my activity? And if I was able to inject it, will it be the new application context, or which context exactly?

I know that in `ActivityUnitTestCase` there is a method [`setActivityContext(Context)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#setActivityContext(android.content.Context)), but in `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` it is not there. Is there another way to set the context?